# Padding in CSS not consistent in Web vs. Mobile

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have the following html code for a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Buy, Sell Anywhere!</title>
<?php
    $bgimglist = array(
    "1419761599136.jpg", 
    "123.jpg", 
    "6Edng.jpg", 
    "second-hand-smoke-2-390x285.jpg",
    "AllSmoke.jpg", 
    "best-air-purifier-for-smoke.jpg", 
    "HTB1pZmkG.jpg", 
    "images.jpg",
    "index.jpg",
    "SmokerBearded.jpg",
    "sygareta.jpg"
    );
    $bgimg = $bgimglist[array_rand($bgimglist)];
?>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(images/<?php echo $bgimg;?>);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
... removed...
</script>
<div id="top">
    <div class="ad">
        <?php include 'Ad728x90.inc';?>
    </div>
<div id="TC">
<p>By using this site, you agree to the terms and conditions.  You also agree that your government, local or national permits you to engage in activities relating to... <removed>...</p>
<p>You must be at least 18 years to use this site, regardless of your local laws.  We do not encourage children to be associated in any way with this site.</p>
</div>
<div id="main">
```

And I have the following CSS:

```
.large {
        font-size:30px;
        }
body    {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
#top {
        font-size:300%;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        padding:19px 0 6px 0;
     }
.ad {
        margin:auto;
        padding:10px;
        text-align:center;
     }
.links  a{
        color:#FFF;
        text-decoration:none!important;
        }
#TC     {
        margin:auto;
        width:90%;
        height: 50px;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:12px;
        background-color:#F0F0F0;
        padding:12px;
        }
#main   {
        margin:auto;
        width:90%;
        height: 500px;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:12px;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        padding: 10px;
        }
```

Most of the CSS  may not be relevant, but I have included it for completeness.  The problem is that the DIV with the id "TC" appears to have bottom padding on the web using Firefox, Chrome and IE; but not on my mobile using Chrome.  In fact, some text is cutoff, so it appears to have a negative padding!

Slightly troubling (maybe this is a different issue) is that the padding on top looks bigger than the padding at the bottom on all browsers, but using Inspect Element in Firefox, the Box Model shows a 10px border for bottom and top.

Any inputs appreciated as always.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing that on smaller screens because the content is overflowing the `#TC` div,
you can make that div bigger, or use `overflow: hidden`, or `overfow-y: scroll` in your css.

For demonstration purposes I have included `overflow-y: scroll`

```
#TC {
        margin:auto;
        width:90%;
        height: 60px;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:12px;
        background-color:#F0F0F0;
        padding:12px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
 }
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/QjZqwx)

Comment: That was easy!  Thanx much!